# PDO could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP Version 5.6.25 that was installed via WAMPP. I'm having issues connecting to my database on mySQL DB:

```
$server = 'jdbc:sqlserver://DB-1\POWERPIVOT;databaseName=SBV_Foldio';
$user = 'sa';
$pass = 'host';
```

I had check PDO extension and already install

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
echo 'PDO is unavailable<br/>';
}
elseif (defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO is available<br/>';
}
```

> PDO is available

but when i run connection

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO($server, $user, $pass);

$dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

it failed

> Error!: could not find driver

Comment: `phpinfo();` check if you have pdo_mysql in there. In case you are on *Linux*: check whether you have the proper packages installed: `dpkg --get-selections | grep php5-mysql`

Comment: yeah i have pdo_mysql block in there phpinfo()

Comment: Your problem is that you don't have the PDO_ODBC module installed. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php - **UPDATE:** I wrote an answer.

Comment: I'm using window, and i had enabled all the extension i can in php.init but still dont work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have the **PDO_ODBC** module installed right now. PDO seems to be properly configured & installed. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php for more info.

You are obviously running windows, so:

> On Windows, php_pdo_odbc.dll has to be enabled as extension in php.ini. It is linked against the Windows ODBC Driver Manager so that PHP can connect to any database cataloged as a System DSN, and is the recommended driver for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server databases.

Comment: tks but i cant do anything xD